# Vuex + Typescript: Mutation Object Payloads are Always Undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

During runtime, the object payload I pass as a secondary parameter to my Vuex mutation method is always `undefined`. Both my Vuex and component files are written in TypeScript.

My `index.ts` file for my Vuex store looks like this (note that I'm using the modular store approach):

```
import Profile from '@/models/Profile'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

const userModule = {
  state: () => ({
    profile: Profile
  }),
  mutations: {
    setProfile (state:any, profile: Profile) {
      // `state` is the local module state
      state.profile = profile //**RUNTIME ERROR: profile = undefined
    } 
  },
  getters: {
    getProfile (state:any) {
      return state.profile
    }
  }
}

export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    user: userModule
  }
})
```

I commit to the store from my Vue component's `methods` like this:

```html
 <script lang="ts">
 export default Vue.extend({
    methods: {
      fetchProfile() {
        axios
            .get("/getUser", requestHeader)
            .then((profileResponse: Profile) => {
              //store profile in Vue Store
              store.commit('setProfile', profileResponse)
            })
      }
    }
 })
 </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is profileResponse definitely not undefined when you commit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `axios.get().then()` callback has a parameter of type [`AxiosResponse`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/f472e5d/index.d.ts#L76-L83), which wraps the actual response in its `data` property. The code should look like this:

```js
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

axios.get(/*...*/)
  .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
    const profileResponse = response.data
    store.commit('setProfile', profileResponse)
  })
```